# Rust Serde - Custom deserialization from map or list

Tags: json, rust, serialization, yaml, serde

I have a problem in doing a custom deserialization in serde: my goal is to be able to deserialize a list of structs or a map of structs, which has the "id" field of each individual struct as its key, into a list.
Basically, my goal is to be able to get code like the following to work:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn deserialize() {
        #[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
        struct List {
            entries: Vec<Entry>,
        }

        #[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
        struct Entry {
            #[serde(flatten)]
            class: Class,
            label: Box<str>,
        }

        #[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
        #[serde(tag = "class")]
        enum Class {
            ClassOne(ClassOne),
            ClassTwo(ClassTwo),
        }

        #[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
        struct ClassOne {
            value: u32,
        }

        #[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
        struct ClassTwo {
            value: f32,
        }

        // ------------------------------

        let input_list = r#"
            entries:
                - class: ClassOne
                  value: 1234
                  label: Test#1
                - class: ClassTwo
                  value: 1.234
                  label: Test#2
                - class: ClassOne
                  value: 4321
                  label: Test#3
        "#;

        let input_map = r#"
            entries:
                ClassOne:
                    value: 1234
                    label: Test#1
                ClassTwo:
                    value: 1.234
                    label: Test#2
                ClassOne:
                    value: 4321
                    label: Test#3
        "#;

        // This works
        let list = serde_yaml::from_str::<List>(input_list).unwrap();
        println!("{list:?}");

        // This panics (as expected)
        //let list = serde_yaml::from_str::<List>(input_map).unwrap();
        //println!("{list:?}");
    }
}
```

---

Initially I thought about using the `Visitor` trait, I need it to be as generic as possible because I have various structures that, from specification, behave like the one in the test above, but I got stuck here (in the error in the form of a comment):

```rust
use serde::{
    de::{MapAccess, SeqAccess, Visitor},
    Deserialize,
};

pub(crate) struct MapOrListVisitor<T, A> {
    insert: Box<dyn Fn(&str, &mut A) -> T>,
}

impl<'de, T, A> MapOrListVisitor<T, A>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    A: MapAccess<'de>,
{
    pub fn new(insert: impl Fn(&str, &mut A) -> T + 'static) -> Self {
        Self {
            insert: Box::new(insert),
        }
    }
}

impl<'de, T, A> Visitor<'de> for MapOrListVisitor<T, A>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    A: MapAccess<'de>
{
    type Value = Box<[T]>;

    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut std::fmt::Formatter) -> std::fmt::Result {
        todo!()
    }

    fn visit_map<M>(self, mut map: M) -> Result<Self::Value, M::Error>
    where
        M: MapAccess<'de>,
    {
        let entries = Vec::<T>::with_capacity(map.size_hint().unwrap_or_default());

        while let Some(key) = map.next_key::<Box<str>>()? {
            let entry = (&self.insert)(&key, &mut map);
            // mismatched types
            //     expected mutable reference `&mut A`
            //     found mutable reference `&mut M`

            todo!()
        }

        Ok(entries.into_boxed_slice())
    }

    fn visit_seq<S>(self, seq: S) -> Result<Self::Value, S::Error>
    where
        S: SeqAccess<'de>,
    {
        todo!()
    }
}
```

---

Would anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: Are your lists always `Vec`s?

Comment: This is as close as I've been able to get (not yet generic) https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3045e7d4b0a8d2d55a202cc6fb0e554

Comment: Do you need to deserialize both `input_list` and `input_map`, or only `input_map`?

Comment: `serde_with` implements this: [`EnumMap`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/struct.EnumMap.html). It doesn't work with flattened enums, but you can look how it's implemented.

Comment: @PitaJ I thought that making the list and the map result in one list would be easier.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman both.

Comment: The type serde_with::KeyValueMap almost implements your desired solution. However it requires that the enum tag is `$key$`, so it does not work with your current lost format. Changing the hardcoded key is not easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solution to this problem is tricky, as the two separate data formats you need to support cannot easily be addressed at the same time using `serde`'s derive attributes. [@PitaJ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847382/pitaj)'s presented solution in the comments above (which, for reference, is viewable [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a3045e7d4b0a8d2d55a202cc6fb0e554)) is not generic, as they rightly pointed out, due to having to basically reimplement deserialization for the map case for every single struct contained within `Class`. To adequately solve this problem in a way that doesn't require constant tuning of our deserialization logic, we must create a `Deserialize` implementation for `Entry` that is generically usable in both the `seq` and `map` contexts, and then implement logic to deserialize `Entry`s in both data formats using that implementation.

Warning: there will be a good amount of boilerplate in this solution. As I mentioned, we won't be able to take advantage of `serde` derive attributes in many parts of this solution, including the [`flatten`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#flatten) attribute you were using in your minimal example. However, once the boilerplate is put in place, there will be very little changes required when expanding to more variants within the `Class` `enum`.

## Deserializing `Entry`s

One of the toughest parts about the two data formats presented in your question is that we encounter the `Class` variant at different points during the deserialization process: for `input_list`, the `class` field is present alongside the other fields in the flattened `struct`, while in `input_map` the variant is the map's key. Rather than implementing two separate deserialization strategies for both cases, we instead want to use a deserialization strategy that can handle both cases. Therefore, deserializing the `Entry` `struct` should always begin by first obtaining the `Class` variant. From that point, we can use the variant to deserialize the rest of the flattened `Entry` struct.

Begin by defining a `ClassVariant` `enum`. Defining a separate `enum` just to encode the variant may seem weird, but this is actually a common strategy for manually deserializing `enum`s (see `serde`'s own [`Deserialize` implementation for `Result`](https://docs.rs/serde/1.0.175/src/serde/de/impls.rs.html#2820-2924), for example).

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
enum ClassVariant {
    ClassOne,
    ClassTwo,
}
```

To reiterate, in the case of `input_list`, this is deserialized from a field. In the case of `input_map`, this is deserialized from a key.

### `ClassVariant` as a key

Let's address the case of `ClassVariant` being deserialized from a key first, as this is the simpler case. Given a deserialized `ClassVariant`, we can deserialize an `Entry` using the variant as a seed by implementing [`DeserializeSeed`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.DeserializeSeed.html). While we can't use the `flatten` attribute, we can instead use the [`serde-value`](https://crates.io/crates/serde-value) crate to implement the exact same strategy the derived code uses (see [prior discussion](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1028) for a similar problem).

```rust
use 

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct ClassOne {
    value: u32,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct ClassTwo {
    value: f32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Class {
    ClassOne(ClassOne),
    ClassTwo(ClassTwo),
}

impl<'de> DeserializeSeed<'de> for ClassVariant {
    type Value = Entry;

    fn deserialize<D>(self, deserializer: D) -> Result<Self::Value, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        enum Field {
            Label,
            Other(String),
        }

        impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Field {
            fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
            where
                D: Deserializer<'de>,
            {
                struct FieldVisitor;

                impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for FieldVisitor {
                    type Value = Field;

                    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                        formatter.write_str("`label`")
                    }

                    fn visit_str<E>(self, value: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
                    where
                        E: de::Error,
                    {
                        match value {
                            "label" => Ok(Field::Label),
                            name => Ok(Field::Other(name.to_owned())),
                        }
                    }
                }

                deserializer.deserialize_identifier(FieldVisitor)
            }
        }

        struct EntryVisitor(ClassVariant);

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for EntryVisitor {
            type Value = Entry;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("struct Entry")
            }

            fn visit_map<A>(self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: MapAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut label = None;
                let mut values = BTreeMap::new();

                while let Some(field) = map.next_key()? {
                    match field {
                        Field::Label => {
                            if label.is_some() {
                                return Err(de::Error::duplicate_field("label"));
                            }
                            label = Some(map.next_value()?);
                        }
                        Field::Other(name) => {
                            values.insert(Value::String(name), map.next_value()?);
                        }
                    }
                }

                let label = label.ok_or_else(|| de::Error::missing_field("label"))?;
                let class = match self.0 {
                    ClassVariant::ClassOne => Class::ClassOne(ClassOne::deserialize(
                        ValueDeserializer::new(Value::Map(values)),
                    )?),
                    ClassVariant::ClassTwo => Class::ClassTwo(ClassTwo::deserialize(
                        ValueDeserializer::new(Value::Map(values)),
                    )?),
                };

                Ok(Entry { class, label })
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_map(EntryVisitor(self))
    }
}
```

This is similar to code presented in [Manually implementing Deserialize for a struct](https://serde.rs/deserialize-struct.html), but instead of implementing `Deserialize,` we implement `DeserializeSeed` that will return a value of type `Entry`. The overall strategy is to deserialize each key as either the `label` field, or an unknown `Other` field which contains the flattened fields contained in `Class`'s variant. We collect the unknown fields into a `BTreeMap` which can then be re-deserialized using [`serde_value::ValueDeserializer`](https://docs.rs/serde-value/0.7.0/serde_value/struct.ValueDeserializer.html) as either `ClassOne` or `ClassTwo`, depending on the `ClassVariant` seed. This re-deserialization allows us to derive a `Deserialization` implementation for the contained `struct`s, and works nearly identical to `serde`'s `flatten` attribute (see the [source code](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/blob/master/serde_derive/src/de.rs#L2553-L2560), which uses a private deserializer for the same purpose).

Note also that we have to reallocate for the unknown field names; this is a limitation with `serde-value`; there is an [open issue](https://github.com/arcnmx/serde-value/issues/15) that has had little traction.

### `ClassVariant` as a field

In the case of `input_list`, the `ClassVariant` is provided in the `class` field. Therefore, if we can first extract the variant using a similar strategy as that used above for re-deserializing the other fields, we can reuse the rest of the deserialization logic we have already implemented.

We therefore implement `Deserialize` for `Entry`, but only extract the `class` field, deferring the remainder of the deserialization to `ClassVariant`'s `DeserializeSeed` implementation.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Entry {
    class: Class,
    label: Box<str>,
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Entry {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        enum Field {
            Class,
            Other(String),
        }

        impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Field {
            fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
            where
                D: Deserializer<'de>,
            {
                struct FieldVisitor;

                impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for FieldVisitor {
                    type Value = Field;

                    fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                        formatter.write_str("`class`")
                    }

                    fn visit_str<E>(self, value: &str) -> Result<Self::Value, E>
                    where
                        E: de::Error,
                    {
                        match value {
                            "class" => Ok(Field::Class),
                            name => Ok(Field::Other(name.to_owned())),
                        }
                    }
                }

                deserializer.deserialize_identifier(FieldVisitor)
            }
        }

        struct EntryVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for EntryVisitor {
            type Value = Entry;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("struct Entry")
            }

            fn visit_map<A>(self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
            where
                A: MapAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut class: Option<ClassVariant> = None;
                let mut values = BTreeMap::new();

                while let Some(field) = map.next_key()? {
                    match field {
                        Field::Class => {
                            if class.is_some() {
                                return Err(de::Error::duplicate_field("class"));
                            }
                            class = Some(map.next_value()?);
                        }
                        Field::Other(name) => {
                            values.insert(Value::String(name), map.next_value()?);
                        }
                    }
                }

                let class = class.ok_or_else(|| de::Error::missing_field("class"))?;

                class.deserialize(ValueDeserializer::new(Value::Map(values)))
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_map(EntryVisitor)
    }
}
```

Now we can fully deserialize `Entry`s in both the `seq` and `map` contexts.

## Deserializing `List` as a `seq` or a `map`.

We still need to write a bit more custom deserialization logic for the `List` `struct`. However, due to our excellent `Entry` implementation, this is relatively painless. By using the [`deserialize_with`](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with) attribute, we can easily derive a `Deserialize` implementation for `List` by providing a custom function to deserialize the `entries` field.

As you mentioned, the `Visitor` trait can be used here to instruct the deserializer how to visit both `map`s and `seq`s, and we can use [`Deserializer::deserialize_any()`](https://docs.rs/serde/latest/serde/de/trait.Deserializer.html#tymethod.deserialize_any) to let the deserializer choose which one to use based on the context. For `seq`s, we can rely on `Entry`'s `Deserialize` implementation, and for `map`s we first deserialize a `ClassVariant` and rely on its `DeserializeSeed` implementation.

```rust
fn deserialize_entries<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<Entry>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    struct EntriesVisitor;

    impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for EntriesVisitor {
        type Value = Vec<Entry>;

        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            formatter.write_str("either a sequence or map of entries")
        }

        fn visit_seq<A>(self, mut seq: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
        where
            A: SeqAccess<'de>,
        {
            let mut entries = Vec::new();

            while let Some(entry) = seq.next_element()? {
                entries.push(entry);
            }

            Ok(entries)
        }

        fn visit_map<A>(self, mut map: A) -> Result<Self::Value, A::Error>
        where
            A: MapAccess<'de>,
        {
            let mut entries = Vec::new();

            while let Some(variant) = map.next_key::<ClassVariant>()? {
                entries.push(map.next_value_seed(variant)?);
            }

            Ok(entries)
        }
    }

    deserializer.deserialize_any(EntriesVisitor)
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct List {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "deserialize_entries")]
    entries: Vec<Entry>,
}
```

This code can deserialize both `input_list` and `input_map` in your example. It is also generic; to expand to more `struct`s in `Class`, simply add the new `struct` variant in the `Class` `enum`, add a new variant in `ClassVariant`, and slightly modify the `DeserializeSeed` implementation to call the new `struct`'s `Deserialize` implementation for that variant. While adding a new `struct` still requires a tiny bit of boilerplate, it is nothing compared to reimplementing the `Deserialize` implementations for each of those cases.

The full solution can be run, with your examples, on this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fe08768e3531780374d9db9bd0110c70).